# Can I use LINQ queries to join and filter F# sequences?

Tags: f#

I am working with some F# sequences and I need to perform a join to compare them. It will be convenient to use the query expression syntax with a LINQ query. The examples I have found so far show query expressions being used with SQL or other external data sources.

Can sequences be used as the data source for query expressions?

Comment: I never tried but there might be a *hack* using [Linq.QuerySource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh324048.aspx) ... but maybe you should rethink this and try to use what you've got from the Seq-Module ... what exactly do you have to compare?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `query { .. }` syntax in F# on both databases and in-memory queries:

```
let people = [("Tomas",1); ("Joe",2); ("Don",1)]
let places = [(1,"Cambridge"); (2, "Wisconsin")]

query {
  for person in people do
  join place in places 
    on (snd person = fst place)
  select (fst person, snd place) }
```

Comment: That's perfect! That syntax is much nicer than the nested Array.filter expressions I was using.

Comment: I have a follow up question on the syntax with an exists test if you don't mind: I can find things that exist in another array with `for item in arr do exists (i.field = b.field)` but I can't figure out how to negate that and test for not exists.

Comment: I suspect you might be looking for `where` (to filter items) - because `exists` is aggregation that returns a boolean value, but it's a bit hard to say from the minimal example...

Comment: `let foo = query { for item in arr do exists (i.field = b.field) } |> not`